# How to send parameters to uwp app from command line

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp

I am trying to use the new print dialog box for windows 10 in my app to print photos. To open this dialog box, I am using the command:

```
explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Windows.PrintDialog_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Windows.PrintDialog
```

I am getting `Windows.PrintDialog_cw5n1h2txyewy` from the powershell command `GetAppX-Package`. This points me to the install location (`C:\Windows\PrintDialog`) from where I can now get the manifest. Inside the manifest is the AppId which is `Microsoft.Windows.PrintDialog`.
My command runs successfully and opens the dialog box. However it says "Nothing was sent to print. Open a document and print again" which is correct as I have not sent any file.

My question is, does anyone know how I can send a file or list of files to this command?

Many Thanks

Comment: [`Out-Printer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: No, I am trying to use the modern UWP dialog box

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can send to that dialog that'll create a new print job. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Trying to use the new printer dialog for my app basically. I know there are other ways to print just trying to use this particular one

Comment: @daibatzu how this ‘explorer’ command is invoked from your app?

Comment: I am spawning a cmd.exe process and feeding the command into it